How to use strict types of data attributes in react typescript?
I am developing something with react + typescript + vite. And testing using cypress. For that I am using data-testid. The issue is that there are so many test ids and if I get some of them wrong in spelling it create issue.
Is there any way I could strictly use a type data-testid for all my divs or html elements?
So far I have tried using the following but it is not working
//typings.d.ts
import { DOMAttributes, AriaAttributes } from "react";
type TestId = "testid1" | "testid2"
declare module "react" {
   interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends AriaAttributes, DOMAttributes<T> {
      "data-testid"?: TestId;
   }
}

Here is App.tsx file
//App.tsx
function App() {
   return <div data-testid="abc"></div>;
}

export default App;

I want this above App.tsx file to give error because test is not correct.

in react playground your code is working. Maybe your setup with typings.d.ts is not right
